# Vertical Line Coding

Tags: html, css

So what im trying to do is have three vertical lines separating images in columns on a website however every time i go out of the editor and preview the website the position of the lines seems to change. I am not sure if this is because i have missed something or have a fault so please help me i am new to html and css
:/

```css
div#left {
  background-color: clear;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  top: 275px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}

div#leftt {
  background-color: clear;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  top: 275px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  position: absolute;
}

div#right {
  background-color: clear;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  top: 275px;
  margin-left: 810px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="background-color: clear; width: 100%; height: 80%;">
  <div id="left">
  </div>
  <div id="leftt">
  </div>
  <div id="right">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use `flex` positioning.

You can learn more about Flex [following this link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
}

.container > * {
 flex: 1;
 text-align: center;
}

.container > *:nth-child(2) {
 border: 0 solid black;
 border-width: 0 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span>item 1</span>
    <span>item 2</span>
    <span>item 3</span>
</div>
```